# Проблемы с удалением EditText элемента при использовании RecycleView

Tags: android, recyclerview, android-edittext, recyclerviewadapter

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой.
Есть список EditText элементов, для отображения используется RecycleViewAdapter.
Если я ввожу данные в EditText, а потом удаляю элемент списка, то элемент списка удаляется, а вот значения сдвигаются вниз на 1 элемент по списку.

Т.е:

```
1. EditText ("Ford") <-удаляем
2. EditText ("Mazda") 
3. EditText ("Opel")
```

Становиться так:

```
2. EditText ("Ford") 
3. EditText ("Mazda")
```

Есть ли у кого соображения?

Обновляю список так:

```
//Передаем новый ArrayList
public void update(ArrayList list){
        this.list.clear();
        this.list.addAll(list);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
  }
```

Comment: Проверьте какой лист подаётся на вход update()

Comment: Показывайте сразу код адаптера, как удаляете элемент, как и где обновляете список.